# Can psake ignore dependent tasks?

Tags: psake

In PSake, is there an option to request that dependent tasks are not not run. For example:

```
In a build script, Build.ps1:
    Task T1 {}
    Task T2 -depends T1 {}
```

Is it possible to do `Invoke-psake .\Build.ps1 T2 -ignoredependencies`?

The reason for this is that with large projects, testing of tasks that have large number of dependencies (directly or indirectly) takes a long time since all the the dependencies are rebuilt but generally do not need.

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement

Comment: You can try -precondition: https://github.com/psake/psake/wiki/How-can-I-conditionally-run-a-task%3F